# How to install a private Firefox WebExtensions extension (not via AMO)

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

We are developing a Firefox extension that is only used internally and not available publicly via the AMO.  How do we install it?  Obviously, the temporary install method via about:debugging won't work since it's only temporary.

Comment: See: [Signing and distributing your add-on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Distribution).  Specifically "[Unlisted Add-ons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Distribution#Unlisted_add-ons)". Or are you asking what to do once you have the signed version of your add-on?

Comment: @Makyen I do not have a signed version.  The doc you pointed to says that the add-on has to be reviewed before it can be signed (even for unlisted add-ons).  This add-on can't go through review b/c it is developed and used internally in a corporate private setting.

Comment: Your only option to install unsigned add-ons is into a non-release/non-beta version of Firefox, or a release/beta version prior to version 48.  Any of:[Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/), or [Firefox Nightly](https://nightly.mozilla.org/), [Unbranded Beta, or Unbranded Release](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Add-ons/Extension_Signing#Unbranded_Builds). You can not install unsigned add-ons (other than as a temporary add-on, which you would have to re-install every time you run Firefox) into a branded release/beta version of Firefox version >=48.0. [continued]

Comment: [continued]  I know there are some valid reasons to not want *any* review.  However, for unlisted add-ons: "Unlisted add-ons are for the most part automatically reviewed and signed. The add-ons review team may from time to time perform a manual review of your signed files and give you feedback about it."